# Which http headers are stripped out by the Sharepoint Web Proxy in SP Online?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, web-services, jsom

I've used the Azure API management gateway to intercept traffic from the SP web proxy and I've learned the following about its behavior with HTTP headers:

- Custom headers are passed through
- Content-Type, Accept headers are passed through
- Authorization headers are removed
- Azure API trace headers (Ocp-Apim-Trace) are removed

Is there any source that tells a developer what is removed and what is allowed through the web proxy?

Thanks!!